# Generalizing $g = \Sigma^{-1/2}N$ where $g\sim \mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$ and $N$ is standard Gaussian to singular $\Sigma$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\theta \sim \mathcal N(0,AA^T)$ where $AA^T \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is singular. Is it possible to write $\theta = A\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,I_n)$? Here I am asking for equality almost surely, and not equality in distribution, the latter of which is clearly true. A naive approach would be to try $\epsilon = A^\dagger \theta$, but this does not work; one issue is $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,AA^\dagger)$.

More generally, we can ask if we can write $\theta = A\epsilon$ for $\epsilon \sim \mathcal N(0,I_d)$ where $\theta \in \mathbb R^n$ is distributed $\theta \sim \mathcal N(0,AA^T)$. Here, $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times d}$. Feel free to consider any restrictions on $A$, e.g. $d<n$ or $n<d$ or $AA^T$ is non-singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, even for the general case $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times d}$.

Write the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) $A=U\Sigma V^T$, where $U\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $V\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma\in\mathbb R^{n\times d}$ has zero coefficients everywhere except the first $r$ diagonal coefficients $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_r>0$ for some $r\in\mathbb N$. Denote by $\Sigma^{-1}\in\mathbb R^{d\times n}$ the matrix $\Sigma^T$ whose coefficients $\lambda_i$ are replaced with $1/\lambda_i$, so that $\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma$ is the diagonal matrix $J\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ with $1$ on its first $r$ diagonal entries and $0$ elsewhere. Then
$$
U^T\theta\sim\mathcal N(0,U^TAA^TU)=\mathcal N(0,\Sigma\Sigma^T).
$$

We deduce that the last $n-r$ components of $U^T\theta$ are $0$. Moreover, $$\Sigma^{-1}U^T\theta\sim\mathcal N(0,\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma\Sigma^T(\Sigma^{-1})^T)=\mathcal N(0,J).$$

Therefore $\Sigma^{-1}U^T\theta=(\eta_1,\cdots,\eta_r,0,\cdots,0)\in\mathbb R^d$, where $\eta_1,\cdots,\eta_r$ and independent standard gaussian variables. Let $\eta_{r+1},\cdots,\eta_d$ be independent standard gaussian variables, and $\eta=(\eta_1,\cdots,\eta_d)$, so that
$$
\eta\sim\mathcal N(0,I_d)\quad\textrm{and}\quad\Sigma^{-1}U^T\theta=J\eta.
$$

The latter equality can be rewritten as $\Sigma^{-1}(U^T\theta-\Sigma\eta)=0$. As the last $n-r$ components of $U^T\theta$ and $\Sigma\eta$ are $0$, it is equivalent to $U^T\theta=\Sigma\eta$.

Now set $\varepsilon=V\eta$. Then $\varepsilon\sim\mathcal N(0,I_d)$ and
$$
A\varepsilon=AV\eta=U\Sigma V^TV\eta=U\Sigma\eta=UU^T\theta=\theta.
$$